# how do I plot non-ordered data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

plot yaxis is strange for non-ordered data

```
a=[0.0, 1.875, 4.8248495370370375, 7.236701388888889, 11.050578703703705]
b=['26', '37', '44', '64', '64']
c=['95', '89', '87', '80', '100']
d=['226', '214', '204', '185', '239']
plt.plot(a,b); plt.show() ## OK
plt.plot(a,c); plt.show() ## y axis strange
plt.plot(a,d); plt.show() ## y axis strange
```

How do I plot this?

Comment: convert b, c, and d to floats....

Answer (score 1):

You have three lists with items as strings (b, c, d). For correct plotting by coordinates you need to convert it to int or float values like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [0.0, 1.875, 4.8248495370370375, 7.236701388888889, 11.050578703703705]
b = ['26', '37', '44', '64', '64']
c = ['95', '89', '87', '80', '100']
d = ['226', '214', '204', '185', '239']
plt.plot(a, list(map(float, b)))
plt.show()
plt.plot(a, list(map(float, c)))
plt.show()
plt.plot(a, list(map(float, d)))
plt.show()
```